# Subclassed controls not being released

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, memory

We have found a large memory issue in our application.  We have subclassed UITextField and add these to all of our main views. The main views are being dealloced correctly, however the dealloc method in our subclass never gets hit.  Here is our subclass:

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyEntities.h"
#import "MyControlHelper.h"

@interface MyTextField : UITextField {
    MyControlHelper *myHelper;
    UIView *disabledEffect;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyControlHelper *myHelper;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *disabledEffect;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation MyTextField

@synthesize myHelper;
@synthesize disabledEffect;

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){
        myHelper = [[MyControlHelper alloc] init];
        [myHelper setBoundTextField:self];
        [myHelper SetupKeyboardListener];
        [self setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        self.autocorrectionType = FALSE;
        self.delegate = myHelper;
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) init{
    if (self = [super init]){
        myHelper = [[MyControlHelper alloc] init];
        [myHelper setBoundTextField:self];
        [myHelper SetupKeyboardListener];
        [self setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        self.autocorrectionType = FALSE;
        self.delegate = myHelper;
    }

    return self;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]){
        myHelper = [[MyControlHelper alloc] init];
        [myHelper setBoundTextField:self];
        [myHelper SetupKeyboardListener];
        [self setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        self.autocorrectionType = FALSE;
        self.delegate = myHelper;
    }

    return self;

}

-(void)dealloc{
    self.myHelper = nil;
    self.disabledEffect= nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: did the answer below help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You might have an issue with your myHelper reference. You have declared it as `(nonatomic, retain)` property. If your `MyControlHelper` class has a property for your `MyTextField` also being retained, you are building a cyclic reference and your field is retaining myHelper and vice versa.

If this is the case I suggest you declare the property for the textfield within `MyControlHelper` with `(nonatomic, assign)` to resolve the cycle.

It would help to post the code for MyControlHelper, as well.

Comment: Looking at the code, my first suspect would be `boundTextField` ;)

Comment: @deanWombourne Actually that is the property I meant, I just somehow missed to point it out... Thanks (+1)!